# Python API not returning JSON Object

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to do a sample log API in Python. Here's what I have so far:

```
returnobjforfailure = {}
returnobjforfailure['error'] = 'Invalid username or password'
returnobjforfailure['Result'] = 'Failed'
returnobjforfailure['status'] = 0

class Login(Resource):

    def get(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('email', type=str, required=True, help='email required')
        parser.add_argument('password', type=str, required=True, help='password required')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        del parser

        test = user_controller.login(args["email"], args["password"])
        print(args)
        print("the last test")
        print(test)

        test=0
        if test == 0:
            print("inside if")
            result1 = json.dumps(returnobjforfailure)
            print("result1 ==")
            print(result1) 
            return result1
        else:
            print("inside if")
            result1 = json.dumps(returnobjforfailure)
            print("result1 ==")
            print(result1) 
            return result1
```

Is not sending the correct JSON object the print statement is printing a valid JSON object but I am not getting the correct value from browser.

But if I just write:

```
 def get(self):
        result = json.dumps(returnobjforfailure) 
        return result
```

I'm getting the result in my browser.

Comment: You should do return result1 rather than return result

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: FIX YOUR CODE INDENTATION for God's (or who or whatever is or is not in charge) sake !  Python indentation is significant, it's not just a cosmetic thing.

Comment: Show the result that was printed and the result in your browser. Also, your `if` and `else` has the exactly same code :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo, the last line should be:

```
return result1
```

`result` is not defined anywhere in your code.